# UICollectionViewCell not editable in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I am having an issue with modifying user interface elements in my `TrophyCollectionViewCell`s.

When I modify them using the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, it is fine and works as expected. However when I am modifying them in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, no changes occur.

For example, the following is in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` :

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TrophyCollectionViewCell
cell.trophyImageView.hidden = true
cell.reloadInputViews()
```

This does not make `trophyImageView` hidden. It fails to do anything at all.

Editing the underlying data model does work however (this is in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` as well):

```
self.placeHolderArray[indexPath.row] = ""
self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.reloadData()
```

This creates the same effect I desire except I am editing the `collectionView`'s data model to set an incorrect image asset for the specified `trophyImageView`.

> Note: The `placeHolderArray` successfully feeds the `collectionView`
>   image file names which are set to the `UIImage` of
>   `cell.trophyImageView` in the `cellForIndexPath` method.

So why is it that I cannot properly edit the cell's `trophyImageView`?

Here is my full code.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionHolderViewController: MainPageContentViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionViewController = UICollectionViewController()
    var placeHolderArray = ["derplol_trophy", "medallion_of_courage", "derp_trophy", "herp_trophy", "jordy_trophy", "cotton_trophy", "weird_trophy", "rash_trophy"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrophyRoom") as UICollectionViewController

        self.collectionViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

        self.addChildViewController(collectionViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)
        self.collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.delegate = self

        //self.flowLayout!.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TrophyCollectionViewCell
        cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
        cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight //to fix Apple bug.

        cell.trophyImageView.image = UIImage(named: placeHolderArray[indexPath.row]) //THIS WORKS.

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return placeHolderArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TrophyCollectionViewCell

        self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.scrollEnabled = false // disable scrolling so view won't move
        let innerOffset = collectionView.contentOffset as CGPoint // offset of content view due to scrolling
        let attributes = self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!
        let cellRect = attributes.frame // frame of cell in contentView

        var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x + innerOffset.x, cellRect.origin.y + innerOffset.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: placeHolderArray[indexPath.row]) //change.
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        var trophyCase = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x + innerOffset.x, cellRect.origin.y + innerOffset.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height))
        trophyCase.image = UIImage(named: "trophy_case")
        trophyCase.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        self.view.addSubview(trophyCase)

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)


        cell.trophyImageView.hidden = true //THIS DOES NOT WORK.
        cell.reloadInputViews()

        //self.placeHolderArray[indexPath.row] = ""

        //self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.reloadData()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            imageView.frame = self.view.frame
            trophyCase.frame = self.view.frame
            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
        })
    }
}
```

My cell's class, which is set in interface builder correctly.

```
import UIKit

class TrophyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var trophyImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

}
```

What is so odd is that my `UICollectionView` can modify the `trophyImageView` in `cellForIndexPath` but not in `didSelectAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the cell in didSelectItemAtIndexPath anyway -- if you do, whatever change you make will show up at a different indexPath when the cell is reused.

Comment: That is true, although I am curious as to why this is occurring (why are no edits to trophyImageView happening properly?). Keep in mind that I actually disable the scrollView when a cell is selected, so it won't be loading additional cells.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need this line `self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.reloadData()`?

It seems like it was reloaded before the animation starts to kicks in.

**EDIT**

I was referring to..

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  ....
  cell.trophyImageView.hidden = true //THIS DOES NOT WORK.
  //cell.reloadInputViews()
  self.placeHolderArray[indexPath.row] = ""

  self.collectionViewController.collectionView!.reloadData() <<< THIS LINE

  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        imageView.frame = self.view.frame
        trophyCase.frame = self.view.frame
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
    })
}
```

Comment: Alternatively i could have reloaded an individual cell. It made no difference in this case. The reload occurred to match the data model to the cell (which removed the current image of trophyImageView for the selected cell).

Comment: @CaptainCOOLGUY, it doesnt seems like the didSelectItemAtIndexPath: saved anything externally. seems like the cycle was `cell display > click > changed > cell refresh > animate`. can you try comment it out?

Comment: Ah I now understand what you mean, it makes no difference if commented or not. But yes it would normally have reset any changes i made to the cell's views. I edited the original post's code to show which code is commented when I run it modifying the trophyImageView.

Comment: In that case, are you trying to use the imageView that is defined in TrophyCollectionViewCell `@IBOutlet var trophyImageView:`? It seems like you redefined the imageView in didSelectAtIndexPath: (you haven't use it)